# Changing DataGridView cell from ComboBox to TextBox

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am programmatically changing a DataGridView cell from a combobox to a textbox.

This code works:

```
dataGridView[dataGridView.Columns["colParam2"].Index, rowIndex] = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
```

This code fails:

```
DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView[dataGridView.Columns["colParam2"].Index, rowIndex];
cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
```

Why?

Comment: What fails? does is throw an `exception`?

Comment: It fails by not setting the cell to a text box.

Answer (score 0):

- The first code example changes a certain DGV cell to be a new type of cell.
- The second first sets `cell` to reference a `DataGridView` cell.

Then it **changes the reference variable** to **point** to a newly created cell **instead**.

So it fails (i.e. **does not change the original** DGV cell) because it simply assigns a new thing to the old **variable** `cell`, not to the DGV's cell..